# Install cassandra 3.10 on windows 10

Tags: python, windows, cassandra

I am trying to install Cassandra on windows 10 localhost.
I am getting error as `Can't detect Python version!`

I am trying this way

Downloaded and extracted Cassandra in `C:\wamp64\apache-cassandra-3.10`

Set `Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted` in Windows powershell

From Windows CMD

```
cd C:\wamp64\apache-cassandra-3.10\bin
C:\wamp64\apache-cassandra-3.10\bin>cassandra.bat -f
```

Cassandra is now running so I stopped it by `Control-C`

Then I try to run `cqlsh` by following command

```
C:\wamp64\apache-cassandra-3.10\bin>cqlsh.bat
```

But I got errror `Can't detect Python version!`

So I download and install Python 2.7.13 in `C:\wamp64\python`

I have added environmental path for python in System Properties `C:\wamp64\python\`

I extracted Thrift in `C:\wamp64\python\thrift-0.10.0`

Then I install Python like this

```
C:\wamp64\python\thrift-0.10.0>python setup.py install
```

But again I am getting error on running `cqlsh` as

```
C:\wamp64\apache-cassandra-3.10\bin>cqlsh.bat
Can't detect Python version!
```

Please see and suggest what step I have missed in installation of Cassandra for this error.

Thanks

**Edit**

I reinstall everything from scratch again carefully and now I am getting this error

```
C:\wamp64\apache-cassandra-3.10\pylib>python setup.py install
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 33, in <module>
    ext_modules=get_extensions(),
  File "setup.py", line 26, in get_extensions
    from Cython.Build import cythonize
ImportError: No module named Cython.Build

C:\wamp64\apache-cassandra-3.10\pylib>cd C:\wamp64\apache-cassandra-3.10\bin

C:\wamp64\apache-cassandra-3.10\bin>python cqlsh localhost 9160
  File "cqlsh", line 20
    python -c 'import sys; sys.exit(not (0x020700b0 < sys.hexversion < 0x03000000))' 2>/dev/null \
                                                                                   ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

C:\wamp64\apache-cassandra-3.10\bin>
```

Please see and suggest any possible way to resolve these error.

Thanks

Comment: You mean Python 2.7.13? Did you allow Python to update your PATH when you installed it?

Comment: And why would you ever install Python within WAMP?

Comment: @cricket_007 Yes Python 2.7.13, Also how to allow Python to update PATH

Comment: It's an option during the Installer, I'm fairly sure... Maybe only Python3 has that option

Answer (score 1):

I have installed latest version of Apache Cassandra 3.11.9 for Windows, My python env variable is already set for python3 (Python 3.8), as I actively use python 3.8. I was continuously getting error, then I installed python2 inside 'Apache Cassandra 3.11.9\bin'. I need not to reset my env variable to python2.

The more on solution:
https://susant.medium.com/simple-way-to-install-cassandra-in-windows-10-6497e93989e6

Answer (score 0):

I think you are following wrong python installation procedures. **please uninstall all the python instances using programs and features section in control panel. then install python obtained from [python.org](https://www.python.org/). ensure add to path option is checked on the time of installation. verify python installation by typing `python` on a CMD window.**

After that cd to your cassandra installation bin folder. type `cassandra.bat -f`. it will successfully launch a cassandra server instance. And never stop it, beacuase cqlsh needs a running cassandra instance.

Then open another CMD window. cd to your cassandra installation bin folder. type `cqlsh`. it will successfully connect to running cassandra server instance. And CMD window will switched to cqlsh console mode.

Successfully tested and verified on Win 7 64 bit with python 2.7 64 bit. *I you have time, please check it on python 3.6 too...*

Comment: Over 2 years later, I'll be the one to let you know that I couldn't get it to work with python 3.7.3.

Also note that for users with both python versions installed (2.7 and 3.x), cqlsh will only search for the cmd labeled `python`. So if your commands to run python are `python3` and `python2`, then make a copy of your python2.exe and rename it to just 'python'.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue as I was running Python3 and Python2 on Windows.

It seems like the problem was with missing PATH to Python2.

To check, run in cmd:

```
python --version
```

If you get nothing, it means that the PATH is not added.

Note:

To add path when installing Python2 you need to scroll down to Customize Python 2.x.x -> Add python.exe to Path (unlike Python 3 where you have a checkbox)